# ORA:00900 Invalid sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00900

i created a procedure with 32 in argument,it sucessfully created.but when i am executing this in back end oracle the errror came ORA:00900 Invalid sql statement

Comment: Please post the SQL procedure you created.

Comment: The error probably has nothing to do with the 32-argument procedure, and everything to do with the syntax you used in your SQL. You need to post some details if you want help.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
SQL>  alter procedure [your procedure name here] compile;
SQL>  show errors
```

...to be able to diagnose the issue from the resulting error output.

Comment: The ORA-900 indicates it's probably not the procedure itself, but the SQL he's using to call it; or, perhaps, the procedure is trying to execute some dynamic SQL. Either way show errors should not show anything, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at view `USER_ERRORS`.

Sometimes, show errors does not show anything when in fact there are errors.  Especially after alter compile.

Finally, re-compile in TOAD or SQL Developer and you can easily navigate to the error.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL Developer you should execute it this way:

```
BEGIN
    YOUR_PROCEDURE(PARAM1, PARAM2);
END;
```

If you use EXECUTE or EXEC (which work in SqlPlus) you get the ORA-00900 error.